# How to create "@property" and "@property=" that are actually methods

Tags: ruby

Is there were a way to make an `@property` into a method with `set` and `get`, so, `@property` would call a method instead of returning an actual property, and `@property = someval` would also call a method instead of assigning to an actual property?

In my project, objects store values in a database. Consider this simple database module that stores records in memory. In my real life project it's a DBM like PostgreSQL:

```
module MyDB
    RECORDS = {}

    def self.create(pk)
        RECORDS[pk] ||= {}
    end

    def self.set(pk, key, val)
        return RECORDS[pk][key] = val
    end

    def self.get(pk, key)
        return RECORDS[pk][key]
    end
end
```

Objects have fields that are stored in that database. So, in this class, the `species` field is stored in and retrieved from the database:

```
class Pet
    def initialize(pk)
        @pk = pk
        MyDB.create(@pk)
    end

    def species=(val)
        MyDB.set @pk, 'breed', val
    end

    def species()
        return MyDB.get(@pk, 'breed')
    end
end
```

A simple use of the `Pet` class could look like this:

```
motley = Pet.new('motley')
motley.species = 'cat'
```

It works currently, but here's where I ran into an annoyance. I did something like this within the class:

```
def some_method(newval)
    @species = newval
end
```

Then, when I ran the code I got this result:

```
motley.some_method 'whatever'
puts motley.species #=> cat
```

Then I realize that wasn't corrent and what I should have done is:

```
def some_method(newval)
    self.species = newval
end
```

I think `@species = newval` makes sense. It *feels* like I'm setting a property of the object.

Is were a way to assign a method to the property, something like:

```
def :@species=(val)
    return MyDB.set(@pk, 'breed', 'val')
end

def :@species
    return MyDB.get(@pk, 'breed')
end
```

Is there a way to do such a thing? Should there be?

Comment: What's wrong with `def species=(val)` and `def species`? That's the usual way to do this sort of thing in Ruby.

Comment: I highly recommend reading all of "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)". It's one of the most referred to pages on SO. Conciseness when asking and answering is a desired trait.

Comment: @tscheingeld : Using `attr_accessor :species`, you can create those methods automatically. Of course they still use under the hood the instance variable `@species` (after all, the species has to be stored somewhere, doesn't it?), but you don't have to mention this instance variable explicit in your code, if you don't like it.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to do such a thing?

No. In Ruby setter and getter methods are the way to get/set the internal state of an object. Instance variables are just lexical variables that are scoped to an instance.

<del>Ruby is a language based on message passing and `@foo = bar` sends the message `=, bar` to the recipient that is the lexical variable `@foo`. If it called `self#@foo=` instead that would break the entire model of the language.</del>

> Should there be?

Hell no.

- Do we really need a completely new language feature just because you find it hard to remember to call `self.foo=` instead of `@foo =`? **No.**
- Would this feature add anything to the language that cannot already be done? **No.**
- Would it break existing code? **Yes**.

Comment: `@foo = bar` doesn't send a message. It assigns the value `bar` to the variable `@foo`. If variables were objects (they are not), you could override the `=` method and achive what the OP is asking for.

Comment: You're right @Stefan - I was trying to make a conceptually point that was really badly worded that it would not make sense from a language design standpoint.